# Show that the following language is decidable by finding the algorithm for the finite automaton

Tags: solution-verification, computer-science, turing-machines, decidability

Given the language $K$ = $\{<M>: M$ is a finite automaton on the alphabet {0,1}) and $L(M)$ contains at least one word of the form $0^k1^l$ with $k,l\geq 0$}. In other words, describe an algorithm with the entry $M$ ( a finite automaton)  and that decide after a finite number of steps if $M$ accept at least one word of the form described above.

So this is my attempt but i am really not sure if my algorithm is good.

we can see that the accepted words can be : 1, 0 , 001, 011, ..000001 , 011111.., 1111111.., 000000.., the empty word can't be in this i think since $l$ would be equal to $k$ (unless i am wrong)

This was my idea about what the finite automaton (it's not required but helpful for automaton) :

[image]

And my algorithm would look something like this:

**Input :** < M >

If q0 is a final state and if a loop of $0$ exists around q0 return **true**

Verify that in $M$ if from q0 we can read a 1 and follow a path that leads us to a final state that can have a loop of 1s, if it exists return **true.**

Else return **false.**

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Either you're mis-stating the problem a little or you're over-assuming. Nothing in the definition of K requires that $k \neq l$; in general, variables are allowed to be equal to each other. So the empty string, "01", "0011", and so on are all acceptable. Also, the third sentence of your algorithm doesn't seem precise enough; if you can just say "verify that we can reach an accepting state where ___", why wouldn't we settle for the algorithm "verify that we can reach an accepting state where the word is of the form $0^k1^l$"?

Comment: @Reese Oh god you're right, i updated my questions, does my algorithm make sens ? We did an example in class and the teacher seems to base his algorithm by looking at the finite automaton. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your algorithm makes more sense now, but still doesn't work well. Remember that looking at a specific automaton must always be only *helpful*, not *essential*; if you're doing anything that depends on particular features of an automation, you're in trouble. In this case, you're still getting tripped up on the particulars; your algorithm will work only if the language includes a lot of allowed strings. What if M accepts only the string 001, and nothing else? Then there will be no loops on accepting states.

Comment: @Reese  ok let's try this one : If q0 is final return true. (not sure if this work) Verify that a path exists in M where from the initial state to an accepting state we have the first transition starts by 0 and is followed by any amount of 1s. Else reject Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got it all wrong, you don't have to construct a finite automata but you are given an encoding of a finite automata you have to decide whether the given automata accept the string of type 0*1*.
The algorithm should be something like this:

1. Convert the given FA to minimal Deterministic Finite Automata.
2. If minimal DFA contains n states, then generate all strings of language from 0*1* of length upto n.
3. Run the strings on a simulated DFA, if any one of the string is accepted the FA $\in$ L, else not.

The algorithm gives both yes and no answer given an encoding of an FA, so it is Turing decidable.
The algorithm is correct as we know that if a string of length n of type 0*1* is not accepted on n-state DFA then and string of length > n will never be accepted from the pumping lemma of regular languages.

Comment: i updated my question, the only thing is that my teacher seem to give the algorithm based on an idea of the automaton, he says what we need to verify in M for it to be accepted, and else return false. He gives a pseudo code to describe it. ( i know that the drawing of the finite automaton is not necessary but can help to determine the algorithm).

Comment: also i am not sure if i understand the step 2, "from 01 of length upton" what does that mean and does this solution check the empty word ? if * = 0. Also why can we have a step that "generate" all strings i am not sure. Do we just imply that an algorithm generates all strings ? Could you explain more this step, thanks.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't 01 it was 0\*1* I forgot to prefix the \* with a \\, as for why we can generate all the strings of that type, because the language is regular which implies it is also recursively enumerable and there exists a Turing machine that can enumerate the strings of the language.

Comment: Also @codetime, why are you making an finite automaton. This language is not regular nor it is meant to be. You should be working on a Turing machine.

Comment: look ill give you an an example in my notes : K = { < M > : M is a finite automaton on a,b and L(M) has at least a word fully made of a (no empty word). The answe is : input : <M>  If initial state is final and a loop of $a$ exists around q0, return true.  Verify that in M, a path without a loop from initial state to a final state such as all the transitions are as only . If a path exist return true. Else return false. So this is why i tend to try to find an algorithm based on the automaton

Comment: But from my notes your answer seems good, but i am just not sure why in the exercise he gave us he looks at the states of the FA and seems to describe an algorithm around it.